# ajax fails in refreshing dataTable used with a Sessionscoped managedBean

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, primefaces, managed-bean

i'm using a session scoped bean and primefaces 3.4 
 i got a problem with my dataTable , when i try to add a row , the the datatable is not refreshed i used ajax update attribute to do it , here a complete explaination (code + tried faild solutions) about this issue  http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25113&p=79105#p79105.
So what is the best way to load dataTable  list(containing data to display) ?

i'll try this but it seems illogical

```
public List<Project> getFullproject() {
  return projectsList(); //<--- try to refresh the data from database when the 

  primeface   data table is updated
```

}

Comment: have you tried to add a form inside of the p:dialog? something like `<p:dialog..><h:form>...</h:form></p:dialog>`

Comment: @akoskm but the datatable is out of the dialog